# Access wifi printer from iOS app in same network but different subnet

Tags: ios, printing, wifi, subnet, uiprintinteractioncntrler

In my project there is a print option where we print a simple pdf file with following code:

```
UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

if  (pic && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData: self.myPDFData] ) {
    pic.delegate = self;
    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = @"PrintPdf";
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    pic.printInfo = printInfo;
    pic.showsPageRange = YES;
    pic.printingItem = self.myPDFData;     
    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =

    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed && error)
            NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %ld",
                  error.domain, (long)error.code);
    };
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [pic presentFromRect:self.printButton.frame inView:self.view animated:YES completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        }];
    } else {
        [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }
}
```

It works fine when I have tested it in the Printer Simulator.  My requirement is that the printer may be on another subnet of the same wifi.  How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to change anything in the code [UIPrintInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/), if the printer will be in the same network then it will be discoverable to `UIPrintInteractionController` and from the pop up you will be able to select the printer.

Comment: Just want to inform IP Address of iPad is :192.168.1.100 and IP Address of Printer is:192.168.2.101 and both are in same network but subnet is different.I see My iPad app is not able to find printer.Please suggest.